# Wordpress: How can I redirect all wordpress tags from subdirectory (subfolder) to another one

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I changed my permalinks and it working fine, but I need to redirect old **tag** folder to **archives/tag** to not lose links which google indexed

below is my .htaccess file in the root of my recipes site http://foodonia.com

```
# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Example: http://foodonia.com/tag/fudge/ should redirect to http://foodonia.com/archives/tag/fudge

I tried to add  each one of blow codes but redirect not working

`#RewriteRule tag/(.*) archives/tag/$1 [NC,L]`

`#RewriteRule  tag/$  /archives/tag/$1     [NC,L]`

`#RewriteRule tag/ /archives/tag [L]`

even I tried `redirect 301 ^/tag/fudge/ http://foodonia.com/archives/tag/fudge/` but it didn't work

I try to search for solution but can't find similar post

Comment: you can see my results not working here  [http://foodonia.com google results](https://www.google.com.eg/?#q=site:foodonia.com%2Ftag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use rules in correct order i.e. to use this 301 first before other WP rules.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule (tag/.*)$ /archives/$1 [NC,NE,L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @ anubhava Thank you very much, It is working now and redirect happen like so  [foodonia.com/tag/fudge](http://foodonia.com/tag/fudge), but I should only but your code at the top of my htaccess, because when I but it down it didn't work ?!

Comment: Yes it's try that this rule has to be before WP rules otherwise WP rules take over and this rule won't even fire.